# area of intersection of at least two circles in a range of (0≤≤1,0≤≤1) using Monte Carlo

Tags: python, matplotlib, montecarlo

I would like to find the area of intersection at least two circle within this range (0≤≤1,0≤≤1) using Monte Carlo. Here is what I have done so far.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Making a class circle and initializing it with its centre and radius
class circle:
    def __init__(self,radius,x,y):
        self.radius = radius
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

#Finding point that lies inside the circle
    def exist_in_circle(self,x1,y1):
        if (self.x-x1)(self.x-x1)+(self.y-y1)(self.y-y1) < self.radius*self.radius :
            return True
        else:
            return False

# initializing plt of matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlim=(-1, 2), ylim = (-1, 2))


# initializing 3 circles as required in the question
c1 = circle(1,1,0.5)
c2 = circle(0.5,0.5,0.5)
c3 = circle(0.4,0.1,0.1)

# plotting circles and a square from (0,0) to (1,1)
a_circle = plt.Circle((c1.x, c1.y), c1.radius,color='r', linewidth=1, fill=False)
ax.add_artist(a_circle)
a_circle = plt.Circle((c2.x, c2.y), c2.radius,color='b', linewidth=1, fill=False)
ax.add_artist(a_circle)
a_circle = plt.Circle((c3.x, c3.y), c3.radius,color='g', linewidth=1, fill=False)
ax.add_artist(a_circle)
ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((0,0), 1, 1,color="k", linewidth=1, fill=False))



# Printing the graph
plt.show()
```

This is my current output.
[image: this is my current output]

Here is my expected output using.

[image]

Any technic or approach on how to solve it using Monte Carlo method. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Monte Carlo will never give you fully filled area. Also the result of this method is the approximation of the complex shape, by sampling points in given range.

Comment: Is there another method to solve it except Monte Carlo ?

Comment: "I would like to find the area of intersection.. " so you should expect a number, and then you are writting "Here is my expected output using.." and you post an image with graphic representation of the intersection area. You need to decide if you want an area approximation, or a graphic visualization.

Comment: I want graphic visualization representing the area of intersection

Comment: You are missing * sign in `exist_in_circle` method: `(self.x-x1)*(self.x-x1)+(self.y-y1)*(self.y-y1) < self.radius*self.radius :`

Comment: Ok, plotting circles intersection in matplotlib is not as simple as I thought. People use other tools like sharpely or plotly. I've created MonteCarlo approximation of area and used the points to fill that area with dots, checkout the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use MonteCarlo method first you need to generate meshgrid 1x1

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
print(x.shape, y.shape, xx.shape, yy.shape)
(100,) (100,) (100, 100) (100, 100)
```

Then you need a function that tells you if point is lying inside or outside the desired area. I've used logic present in the examples you have provided, but this function should be changed if other intersection rules are used.

```py
def in_area(point):
    if c1.exist_in_circle(*point) and c2.exist_in_circle(*point):
        return True
    if c1.exist_in_circle(*point) and c3.exist_in_circle(*point):
        return True
    return False
```

Then you iterate through points and create a binary list that counts points inside desired area.

```py
c = []
for x, y in zip(np.ravel(xx), np.ravel(yy)):
    is_in_area = in_area((x, y))
    c.append(is_in_area)
```

To calculate area simply calculate proportion of points inside the area. Important: we are using points inside the identity square 1x1, so I ommit the step of scaling it because the area of that square is 1.

```py
area = sum(c)/len(c)
print(area)
0.8002
```

Then just plot the results adding this lines to your previous visualization code.

```py
colors = list(map(lambda x: {True: 'b', False: 'w'}[x], c))
plt.scatter(np.ravel(xx), np.ravel(yy), c=colors)
plt.title(f'Area: {area}')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The area is filled with dense dots - it's not a full shape.

Comment: I just have a problem with this function ` plt.scatter(np.ravel(xx), np.ravel(yy), c) ` valueError

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I am getting an error coming from this function plt.scatter(np.ravel(xx), np.ravel(yy), c). It's saying value error. it's showing something like below.

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in scatter(x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, data, **kwargs)
   3035         vmin=None, vmax=None, alpha=None, linewidths=None, *,
   3036         edgecolors=None, plotnonfinite=False, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 3037     __ret = gca().scatter(
   3038         x, y, s=s, c=c, marker=marker, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
   3039         vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, alpha=alpha, linewidths=linewidths,

Comment: The problem is coming from the last parameter of the function 'c'. it's not working  with the parameter 'c' in it. 'c' is an array of boolean values.

Comment: Which version of matplotlib do you have?

Comment: matplotlib: 3.4.1 version

Comment: Try to upgrade, and then run it

Comment: I upgraded to latest version which is 3.4.2 but it's  still giving me the same error.

Comment: Ok, could you provide the full error message. Your previous comment was only a part of it.

Comment: here is the link would you please check it ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68129305/area-of-intersection-of-circles-visualization-using-matplotlib

Comment: try this: `colors = list(map(lambda x: {True: 'b', False: 'w'}[x], c))
plt.scatter(np.ravel(xx), np.ravel(yy), c=colors)`

Comment: You should not post another question on stackoverflow. You can edit the question and add the error. For example add this line to the question edit: 
"EDIT: I tried this ... ang got this error ... "